How can I fix this python and SQLite3 syntax error?
it keeps throwing a syntax error in python:

Traceback (most recent call last): File
"/Users/abrahamtchoporyan/Desktop/python/Accounting/TableCreation.py",
line 31, in <module> c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
flow_of_Cash ( sqlite3.OperationalError: near "program_ID": syntax
erro

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('DROP TABLE program')
c.execute('DROP TABLE balance')
c.execute('DROP TABLE in_account')
c.execute('DROP TABLE out_account')
#c.execute('DROP TABLE flow_of_Cash')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS program
        (program_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Name TEXT NOT NULL);''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS balance
        (balance_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Balance_Type TEXT NOT NULL,
        Balance_Total REAL NOT NULL);''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS in_account
        (in_account_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Name TEXT NOT NULL,
        Total REAL NOT NULL);''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS out_account
        (out_account_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Name TEXT NOT NULL,
        Total REAL NOT NULL);''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flow_of_Cash (
        flow_of_Cash_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        amount REAL NOT NULL,
        operation_date TEXT NOT NULL,
        operation_description TEXT,

        program_ID INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (program_ID) REFERENCES program (balance_ID),

        program_ID INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (balance_ID) REFERENCES balance (program_ID),

        program_ID INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (in_account_ID) REFERENCES in_account (in_account_ID),

        program_ID INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (out_account_ID) REFERENCES out_account (program_ID),
        );''')

conn.commit()
conn.close()

What is the problem???
I tried removing and adding, as removing and adding the spaces to fix the error

Please don't make edits to your question that invalidate existing answers.

Sorry, I’m still new to the programming community and still don’t know what is a healthy practice and not, I’ll make sure I don’t repeat this mistake again, thank you for your assistance.

You're trying to create PROGRAM_ID 4 times in that table. Fields in a table must have unique names.

This was a mistake in copying the code, I re-tried to fix the names and didn't work, I copied a code from an answer and it worked.
Thanks!!!

You have duplicate references to program_ID and you also have incorrect references to (non-existent) foreign keys.
You last table creation should look like:
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flow_of_Cash
        (flow_of_Cash_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        amount REAL NOT NULL,
        operation_date TEXT NOT NULL,
        operation_description TEXT,
        program_ID INTEGER,
        balance_ID INTEGER,
        in_account_ID INTEGER,
        out_account_ID INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (program_ID) REFERENCES program (program_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (balance_ID) REFERENCES balance (balance_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (in_account_ID) REFERENCES in_account (in_account_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (out_account_ID) REFERENCES out_account (out_account_ID)
        );''')

